# Convert String into Date Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert the String "181201" into a Date field in Google Big Query using standard SQL.

Ex. 181201 -> 2018-12-01

I have tried to use the following which worked because the original date I inputted had the entire year spelt out as "2018". However, I do not have the entire year written out in my data set.

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%YY%m%d', '20181201') AS DATE
```

How can I update my query to use only yymmdd to give me yyyy-mm-dd? 
THANK YOU!

Comment: `Y` expects a full four-digit year, for a two digit year you should use `y`.

Comment: I tried using this version, however, I keep receiving the following error Failed to parse input string "000000".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', '181201')
```

Comment: I tried using this version, however, I keep receiving the following error 

Failed to parse input string "000000".